# How do I store Subquery result in variable and use in master query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I need to store `subquery` result in variable and use into master query to save execution time of query otherwise i have to write again same `subquery` for that. The code is given below :

```
select DISTINCT
convert(datetime,substring(o.TransactTime, 0,9), 112) + CONVERT(datetime, substring(o.transacttime,10,LEN(o.transacttime)), 114),
o.clordid,
ack.strategyid,
o.Account, 
o.AllocAccount, 
o.symbol,
o.price,
ISNULL((Select Top 1 L.orderqty from order_msgs_incoming1 L where o.clordid=L.clordid and L.msg_id in (17,18,19,22,59,44) order BY L.transacttime DESC),o.orderqty) orderqty,

o.InClOrdID,
(SELECT  ISNULL(ISNULL((Select Top 1 L.orderqty from order_msgs_incoming1 L where o.clordid=L.clordid and L.msg_id in (17,18,19,22,59,44) order BY L.transacttime DESC),o.orderqty)-sum(ex.LastShares),ISNULL((Select Top 1 L.orderqty from order_msgs_incoming1 L where o.clordid=L.clordid and L.msg_id in (17,18,19,22,59,44) order BY L.transacttime DESC),o.orderqty)) from order_msgs_incoming<TblIndx> ex where
    o.Clordid = ex.clordid 
) RemainingQuantity
from order_msgs_incoming1 o 
/*picking ack rows to update strategyId since StrategyId is null for 43 but populated for 46*/
left outer join order_msgs_incoming1 ack on o.clordid = ack.clordid and ack.msg_id=46
where 
/*row for new order only since that contains all columns values*/
o.msg_id = 43
```

I need like this

```
select DISTINCT
variableValue=ISNULL((Select Top 1 L.orderqty from order_msgs_incoming1 L where o.clordid=L.clordid and L.msg_id in (17,18,19,22,59,44) order BY L.transacttime DESC),o.orderqty) orderqty,

o.InClOrdID,
(SELECT  ISNULL(variableValue-sum(ex.LastShares),variableValue) from order_msgs_incoming<TblIndx> ex where
    o.Clordid = ex.clordid 
) RemainingQuantity
from order_msgs_incoming1 o
```

Please help me .

Comment: Are you still interested in an answer to this old question? This is a good case to use `OUTER/CROSS APPLY`.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare a variable and assign it a value using SELECT clause. Then use the variable in your master query. Please find the code below:

```
DECLARE @variableValue bit;

SELECT @variableValue = ISNULL(
                        (
                        SELECT TOP 1 L.orderqty 
                        FROM order_msgs_incoming1 L 
                        WHERE o.clordid=L.clordid
                        AND L.msg_id in (17,18,19,22,59,44) 
                        ORDER BY L.transacttime DESC
                        )
                        ,o.orderqty
                    )
FROM order_msgs_incoming1 o

SELECT DISTINCT
@variableValue AS orderqty,
o.InClOrdID,
(
    SELECT  ISNULL(variableValue-sum(ex.LastShares)
    ,variableValue) 
    FROM order_msgs_incoming<TblIndx> ex 
    WHERE o.Clordid = ex.clordid 
) RemainingQuantity
FROM order_msgs_incoming1 o
```

You can also use the following code in order to change the subquery so that you can use it in a variable:

```
SELECT TOP 1 L.orderqty 
FROM order_msgs_incoming1 L 
INNER JOIN order_msgs_incoming1 o 
    ON o.clordid=L.clordid
    AND L.msg_id in (17,18,19,22,59,44) 
ORDER BY L.transacttime DESC
```

Comment: Hey I don't take subquery result in separate query and used same in other query.Want to take result in variable and use in master query.

Comment: @NeerajDubey I am not getting your point. You cannot get a "sub query result in a separate query" it either has to be in a table or a variable if it is scalar. I guess I have done the same thing that you want. The value of the column "orderqty" now gets populated from the variable "variableValue".